# Counting how many objects there are in an image

Tags: string, image, object, filepath

I have a absolute file path to a picture as a `string` and I'm wondering how you use the absolute file path to count how many objects there are in the picture? For example, if you have a couple of cirlces in the image, the amount of objects in that image will be 2.

I have no idea what to do with the `string` that contains the absolute file path and how to use it to count how many objects there are in the picture. Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some kind of description of the number of objects in the title (e.g., if your string is something like `C:\foldername\twocircles.jpg`), you won't be able to tell the number of objects in the picture just simply based on the path.

Instead, you'll have to use some kind of image recognition software to count the shapes/objects/faces in the image. There are a LOT of options out there to meet your needs, but here are a few to start looking at:

**Amazon Rekognition:** (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=pac_ps_q4&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=rekognition_nb_pac_search&sc_content=recognition_phrase&sc_detail=image%20recognition&sc_category=rekognition&sc_segment=webp&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=US&sc_geo=namer&sc_outcome=pac&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!243317426600!p!!g!!image%20recognition&ef_id=Wi3NEQAABSyiWgnr:20180125040338:s)) **PROS**: they maintain the service for you which means you basically only have to 1) minor configuring, and 2) provide the image. Also, there are a lot of [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/getting-started.html) out there to get you started. **CONS**: can be difficult to integrate into your application if you are using something other than AWS (e.g. Azure, in-house servers, etc)

**OpenCV** (see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)) **PROS**: OpenCV a well-maintained, well-used, and popular open-source project. Because of this, it's free to use and you can completely customize it to your needs. **CONS**: You'll have to really dive into the code and settings to make sure it works in your case. '

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey! The thing is that it's a coding challenge and the given parameter is the absolute file path to the image. I'm coding in Java so will those two options still work?

Comment: Sounds like an intense coding challenge! Is it online? It'd be helpful to get the link so I can view it. Typically with coding challenge sites, they want you to rely on you using the code you write on their page to solve your problem. My guess is you won't have to use some outside application like the ones I mentioned above..